# How to change vertical alignment of a fraction within an equation

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I have a fraction with a very different numerator height vs. that of the denominator.  I would like to vertically center the fraction in the equation, but it appears as if the \frac{}{} command is aligning the fraction bar instead.  Does anyone have any ideas how I can adjust this?

Here's the output with the minimal code example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        \frac{d i_a}{d\theta}       \\
        \frac{d i_{AB}}{d\theta}    \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \frac{%
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \omega\left( L_2 + L_{lv} + L_m\right)  & -\omega L_m                           \\
            -\omega L_m                             & \omega\left(L_1 + L_{mv} + L_m\right) \\
        \end{bmatrix}
    }%
    {|L|}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        v_{an}  \\
        v_{AB}  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You might do it by using `gathered` around the fraction, but there are much better ways.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        \frac{d i_a}{d\theta}       \\
        \frac{d i_{AB}}{d\theta}    \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \begin{gathered}
    \frac{%
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \omega( L_2 + L_{lv} + L_m)  & -\omega L_m                           \\
            -\omega L_m                             & \omega(L_1 + L_{mv} + L_m) \\
        \end{bmatrix}
    }%
    {|L|}
    \end{gathered}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        v_{an}  \\
        v_{AB}  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        \dfrac{d i_a}{d\theta}       \\[3ex]
        \dfrac{d i_{AB}}{d\theta}    \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \frac{%
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \omega( L_2 + L_{lv} + L_m)  & -\omega L_m                           \\
            -\omega L_m                             & \omega(L_1 + L_{mv} + L_m) \\
        \end{bmatrix}
    }%
    {|L|}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        v_{an}\vphantom{\dfrac{d i_a}{d\theta}}  \\[3ex]
        v_{AB}\vphantom{\dfrac{d i_{AB}}{d\theta}}  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        \dfrac{d i_a}{d\theta}       \\[2ex]
        \dfrac{d i_{AB}}{d\theta}    \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \frac{1}{|L|}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \omega( L_2 + L_{lv} + L_m)  & -\omega L_m                           \\
            -\omega L_m                             & \omega(L_1 + L_{mv} + L_m) \\
        \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        v_{an}  \\[1ex]
        v_{AB}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(1) is ugly.

(2) is bad.

(3) is good.

Comment: After working through the options, I decided the equation seemed a bit awkward as I had first approached it and opted for something like (3) in @egreg's answer.  Thanks for the help.  I learned a lot from the examples.

Answer (score 3):

A minor variation on equation (3) in [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667073/5001), to create a (vertically) compact look:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' environment

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{bmatrix} 
    d i_a/d\theta      \\
    d i_{\!AB}/d\theta 
  \end{bmatrix} = 
  \frac{1}{|L|}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \omega( L_2 + L_{lv} + L_m) & -\omega L_m                \\
    -\omega L_m                 & \omega(L_1 + L_{mv} + L_m) 
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    v_{an}   \\
    v_{\!AB}
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would look odd to have the vinculum (fraction bar) out of alignment with the equals sign. Instead, you might want to consider using `bsmallmatrix`, which requires the `mathtools` package instead of `amsmath`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
        \frac{d i_a}{d\theta}       \\
        \frac{d i_{AB}}{d\theta}    
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    \frac{%
        \begin{bsmallmatrix}
            \omega\left( L_2 + L_{lv} + L_m\right)  & -\omega L_m                           \\
            -\omega L_m                             & \omega\left(L_1 + L_{mv} + L_m\right) 
        \end{bsmallmatrix}
    }%
    {|L|}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        v_{an}  \\
        v_{AB}  
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```